# How do I fix PMD Warning: UseCollectionIsEmpty?

Tags: java, pmd

I'm getting a PMD warning `UseCollectionIsEmpty` and the exact message it gives is:

> Substitute calls to size() == 0 (or size() != 0, size() > 0, size() <
>   1) with calls to isEmpty()

on the last `else if` statement.

My issue is that my statement is checking if my **ArrayList is NOT empty**. But the PMD warning is telling me to change it to **isEmpty(**), which is not what I need to do. What's the work around to fix this?

```java
if (theNeighbors.get(getDirection()) == Terrain.CROSSWALK) {
    myDirection = getDirection();
} else if (theNeighbors.get(getDirection().left()) == Terrain.CROSSWALK) {
    myDirection = getDirection().left();
} else if (theNeighbors.get(getDirection().right()) == Terrain.CROSSWALK) {
    myDirection = getDirection().right();
} else if (myPossDir.size() > 0) {
    myDirection = myPossDir.get(random.nextInt(myPossDir.size()));
} else {
    myDirection = getDirection().reverse(); 
}
```

Comment: You're misreading it. It's talking about the general use of `size()`. In your case, negate the `isEmpty`.

Comment: @PiIlar if by negate `isEmpty` you mean to do `else if (!myPossDir.isEmpty())`, I get a new PMD warning on it "Avoid if (x != y) ..; else ..;" if I do that.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Just reorder them. Do the positive one in the `if`, do the negative one in the else.

Comment: Then switch the last two parts around, do `else if (isEmpty){ } else { } `

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
    } else if (myPossDir.size() > 0) {
        myDirection = myPossDir.get(random.nextInt(myPossDir.size()));
    } else {
        myDirection = getDirection().reverse(); 
    }
```

You should use:

```
    } else if (myPossDir.isEmpty()) {
        myDirection = getDirection().reverse(); 
    } else {
        myDirection = myPossDir.get(random.nextInt(myPossDir.size()));
    }
```

This will make the above PMD warning go away, and it more clearly states your intent, you want to check that the collection is not empty. Using `size()` is for other cases - when you don't compare it to zero.

EDIT: Changed order of ifs, so now you use `isEmpty()` instead of `!isEmpty()` (another PMD warning, and negated `if`s are not as easily readable as not negated ones)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of;

`if ( myCollection.size() > 0)`

you can use

`if(myCollection !=null && !mycollection.isEmpty())`

to fix this PMD error.